# Deploy to Azure, Entity First, newsequentialid error without any sequentialid declared

Tags: azure, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to deploy my site to Azure, as usual. I am using code first migrations. Today I am getting an error around the like this

> deploy error ADD DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [ID];

The table that causes the error is the first alphabetically, so I am worried that it will just start doing this for all of them. Otherwise it was a minor change implemented.

---

My most recent migration looks like

```
  public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.StatsUsersDays",
            c => new
                {
                    ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Date = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    UserID = c.String(),
                    Count = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.StatsUsersDays");
    }
```

with accompanying model

```
public class StatsUsersDays
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public String UserID { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

which really should not be throwing an error like it did.  :(

---

I see two possible questions

1. Did Azure just update their backend in a huge and breaking way?
2. Where do you find the code that is being executed for the code -first deployment migrations that seems to be breaking my publish?

Comment: Surely there's a more detailed error message that just that?  Did you "add a migration" to your entity framework project?  The migration code files will be under a `Migrations` folder in the project where the DbContext is defined.

Comment: I know, right!  I looked through all the migration files.  None refer to the newsequentialid for any of the table's keys.  At most the PK has identity: true.

Comment: That'll be the difference between what the migration code is and what gets generated and executed as SQL.  Please share the most recent migration that you created (that you think it causing the problem) along with the relating models.

Comment: I wonder if the EF conventions are case sensitive.  Have you tried adding the `[Key]` attribute to the `ID` property of your `StatsUserDays` class, and then re-scaffolding the migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure updated the version of MSSql running by default in Azure.  I had to recreate my application and after 40 hours of helpdesk ticket time this issue is resolve.  Woe be to you who has this happen to you as well.  :(